# Is it possible to have multiple joins between two tables in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, "Booking" and "City". CityName field is primary key in City table and I have used it as foreign key for two columns "SourceCity" and "DestinationCity" in Booking table. I want to create a stored procedure to select all existing data from the Booking table for creating a view list, for which I have written the following.

```sql
SELECT  [dbo].[Booking].[BookingID],
        [dbo].[Booking].[CustomerName],
        [dbo].[City].[CityName],
        [dbo].[City].[CityName],
        [dbo].[Booking].[StartingDate],
        [dbo].[Booking].[EndingDate],
        [dbo].[Car].[LicensePlateNumber],
        [dbo].[Driver].[DriverName],
        [dbo].[Booking].[AdvanceTaken],
        [dbo].[Booking].[PendingPayment],
        [dbo].[Booking].[TotalRent],
        [dbo].[Booking].[BookingDate],
        [dbo].[Booking].[IDProof]

FROM [dbo].[Booking]
**LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[City]  
ON [dbo].[Booking].[SourceCity] = [dbo].[City].[CityName]
AND [dbo].[Booking].[DestinationCity] = [dbo].[City].[CityName]**
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Driver]
ON [dbo].[Driver].[DriverID] = [dbo].[Booking].[DriverAllotted]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Car]
ON [dbo].[Car].[CarID] = [dbo].[Booking].[CarAllotted]
ORDER BY [dbo].[Booking].[BookingID]
```

I am not sure if it is possible to do the following

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[City]  
ON [dbo].[Booking].[SourceCity] = [dbo].[City].[CityName]
AND [dbo].[Booking].[DestinationCity] = [dbo].[City].[CityName]
```

Comment: *I am not sure if it is possible to do the following* - so what happened when you tried it?

Comment: You may want to read up on using table [aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). It not only makes it possible to re-use the same table without ambiguity, it also makes your SQL a lot more readable

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/), stick to using aliases, as @GarethD says. Not only will it make your code more succinct, it'll make your code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need a different JOIN

```
FROM [dbo].[Booking] as booking
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[City]  as source_city
ON booking.[SourceCity] = source_city.[CityName]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[City]  as destination_city
ON booking.[DestinationCity] = destination_city.[CityName]
```

....

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you just need to use a different table [alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). Beyond referencing the same table twice, table aliases can make your code look a lot cleaner, e.g.

```
SELECT  b.CustomerName,
        sc.CityName AS SourceCity,
        dc.CityName AS DestinationCity,
        b.StartingDate,
        b.EndingDate,
        c.LicensePlateNumber,
        d.DriverName,
        b.AdvanceTaken,
        b.PendingPayment,
        b.TotalRent,
        b.BookingDate,
        b.IDProof
FROM    dbo.Booking AS b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.City AS sc
            ON sc.CityName= b.SourceCity
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.City AS dc  -- Different Alias here
            ON dc.CityName = b.DestinationCity
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Driver AS d
            ON d.DriverID = b.DriverAllotted
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Car AS c
            ON c.CarID = b.CarAllotted
ORDER BY
        b.BookingID;
```

I appreciate that *cleaner* is somewhat subjective, but I would be astonished if anyone found this harder to read than your original query